# Rails has_many retrieve all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

```
# Events
has_many :attendees

# Attendees
belongs_to :event
```

How can I access All the Events with each Event's Attendees?
`Event.all.attendees # obviously does not work`

To do this for 1 event, we can do
`Event.find(1).attendees`
How can we do this for all events?  Is there an automagic way or do we need a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. there is. [Have a read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) about AR query methods.

There are two main methods to look on:

[`joins`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) and [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes).

```
Event.includes(:attendees)
```

would load all events and it's attendees (whether there are any or none)

```
Event.joins(:attendees)
```

would select those events, which have assigned attendees.

With both options you can then iterate over events' attendees with a block.

---

## Edit

Just a short clarification. I do understand, that you probably needed a result, that can be (**but never should be**) achieved this way:

```
Event.all.map(&:attendees) # would return a collection of attendees.
```

Such queries are evil, since they are fully loaded into memory before execution.

And the point of edit - you would *"never"* actually need such thing, as loading a collection of assigned attendees.

Why?

Because if you ever need a collection of attendees, operate on `Attendee` model, not `Event` or any other associated model.

What that mean, is that you can get some events meeting certain condition(s).

For example:

```
events = Event.where('start_date > ?' Date.today)
```

If you need Attendees for this event, you would rather do this

```
Attendee.where(event_id: events.ids)
```

then this

```
Event.where('start_date > ?' Date.today).map(&:attendees) #inefficient
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to retrieve the Event and their associated Attendee in few SQL queries:

```
events = Event.includes(:attendees)
events.each do |event|
  event.attendees
end
```